# Arduino IDE 1.8.15 won't open

Tags: arduino-ide

I was using Arduino IDE 1.8.13 but didn't open for a few week and now I can't launch the IDE and any of the sketch. I uninstall it and downloaded the latest version 1.8.15 but it still poses the same problem. Only the initializing window appear and after it disappear, the IDE won't go any further. I run the debug.exe and still the same problem. Anyone has same problem and has the solutions?

Comment: run `arduino_debug.exe` from command line to see the log

Comment: Delete your preferences.txt file

Comment: @Majenko That works very well. I see other suggestion to remove the json files. but never the preferences file. Thanks alot